# Qual a diferença entre static::Propriedade, NomeClasse::propriedade, self::propriedade?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade

Sei que o `parent::propriedade`, você seleciona a propriedade da classe pai, mas não estou conseguindo diferenciar esses outros três quando eu uso dentro do escopo da classe. Ambos funcionam, mas qual a diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estamos falando sempre de propriedades estáticas aí.

O `self::propriedade` é a maneira de se referir a uma propriedade estática dentro do código da classe. É como estivesse usando o `this`, mas é para membros estáticos, não só propriedades. Pode usar o nome da classe também.

Já `nomeClasse::propriedade` é o uso da mesma coisa, mas é usado fora do código da classe, ou seja, quando está consumindo a classe.

E `static::propriedade` é como se fosse o `self` mas para constantes e se houver herança nesta classe ele pegará a propriedade estática da classe derivada e não da classe base, se houver uma propriedade estática com mesmo nome na derivada.

```
class A {
    const X = 'A';
    public function x() {
        echo static::X;
    }
}

class B {
    public static $X = 'B';
    public function x() {
        echo self::$X;
    }
    public function x2() {
        echo B::$X;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    const X = 'C';
}

$c = new C();
$c->x();
echo C::X;
echo c::X;
$b = new B();
$b->x();
$b->x2();
echo b::$X;
echo B::$X;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Mp3AXe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdngxlwa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/StaticProperties.php).

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero!